# Angular material toast using Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-material

i am new to Typescript and want to display a Angular Material Dialog with typescript but i am not able to configure the Controller because typescript says "content" does not exist. Which is right but how do i say Typescript that it exists?

Here is my Code:

```
 interface IToastService {
    displayError(text: string): void;
    displaySuccess(text: string): void;
}

export class ToastService implements IToastService {
    public static $inject = ['$mdToast'];
    constructor(
        private $mdToast: angular.material.IToastService) { }

    displayError(text: string): void {
        this.$mdToast.show({
            position: 'top left',
            controller: () => {
                this.content = text; // the Error Line
            },            
            controllerAs: 'toast',
            template: '<md-toast>\
                        {{ toast.content }}\
                        <md-button ng-click="toast.cancel()" class="md-warn">\
                                 <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons"> clear </md-icon>\
                    </md-button>\
                </md-toast>',
            hideDelay: 0
        });
    }

    displaySuccess(text: string): void {

        this.$mdToast.show({

            template: '<md-toast>\
                        {{ toast.content }}\
                           <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons" style="color:#259b24"> done </md-icon>\
                </md-toast>',
            hideDelay: 1000,
            position: 'top left',
            controller: () => {
                this.content = text;
            },
            controllerAs: 'toast'
        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just declare it your class upfront, i.e

```
export class ToastService implements IToastService {
   public content:string; //Here

   public static $inject = ['$mdToast'];
//...
```

But it looks like you are using arrow operator. It means the property `content` will not be attached to the controller instance of the modal, instead to the `ToastService` instance (when the modal controller is instantiated). I believe you would need to declare it as normal function.

```
this.$mdToast.show({
        position: 'top left',
        controller: function() {
            this.content = text; //Now this is your controller instance
        },            
        controllerAs: 'toast',
        //...
    });
```

You should also be able to pass the argument `text` as resolve of the toast and accept it as argument of the controller. i.e

```
    this.$mdToast.show({
        position: 'top left',
        controller: function(content:string) {
            this.content = content; 
            //If you define this as class, you could do "private content:string"
        },            
        controllerAs: 'toast',
        resolve:{
           content: () => text
           //Not sure if it is very specific only about a promise, if so you
           //would need to inject $q and do "content: ()=> $q.when(test)"
        }
        //...
    });
```

Comment: although i didnt understand your second example the first one worked great for me. Thank you!